# Ошибка типа "'NoneType' object is not callable" при использовании декоратора класса

Tags: python, классы, декоратор, type-error

> Необходимо написать декоратор, который загружает файл JSON и делает
> каждую пару ключ-значение этого файла атрибутом данного класса.

Когда тестирую код, то выбивает ошибку `'NoneType' object is not callable`. Возможно, ошибка в написании декоратора и передачи аргументов

```
def jsonattr(filepath):
    def my_decorator(*args):
        import json
        with open(filepath) as f:
            file = json.load(f)
        file_items = file.items()
        list_of_keys = [x for x, y in file_items]
        print(list_of_keys)
        foo = list_of_keys[0]
        an_int = list_of_keys[1]
        this_kata_is_awesome = list_of_keys[2]

    return my_decorator
```

Здесь запускаю свой код:

```
@jsonattr("myClass.json")
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, foo, an_int, this_kata_is_awesome):
        self.foo = foo
        self.an_int = an_int
        self.this_kata_is_awesome = this_kata_is_awesome

instance = MyClass("hello", 2, None)
```

Выдаёт ошибку:

```
input
['foo', 'an_int', 'this_kata_is_awesome']                                                                                  
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                         
File "main.py", line 22, in <module>                                                                                     
instance = MyClass("hello", 2, None)                                                                                   
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Comment: У вас явные проблемы с индентацией в коде вопроса. Отредактируйте код в вопросе, чтобы он был однозначно определим

Comment: если вы имеете в виду отступы, то я код подправила

Comment: вероятно, вы ошиблись табуляцией в `return my_decorator` при копировании кода. Если нет - это и есть причина ошибки. Сдвиньте его на одну табуляцию влево и попробуйте снова. При текущей табуляции `jsonattr` действительно возвращает `None`

Answer (score 2):

Исправление кода из вопроса:

```
import json


def jsonattr(filepath):
    def decorator(cls):
        def wrapper(*args):
            with open(filepath) as f:
                file = json.load(f)
            file_items = file.items()
            list_of_keys = [x for x, y in file_items]
            print(list_of_keys)
            foo = list_of_keys[0]
            an_int = list_of_keys[1]
            this_kata_is_awesome = list_of_keys[2]
            
            return cls(foo, an_int, this_kata_is_awesome, *args)

        return wrapper
    
    return decorator


@jsonattr("myClass.json")
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, foo, an_int, this_kata_is_awesome):
        self.foo = foo
        self.an_int = an_int
        self.this_kata_is_awesome = this_kata_is_awesome
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.__class__.__name__}({self.foo!r}, {self.an_int!r}, {self.this_kata_is_awesome!r})'


instance = MyClass("hello", 2, None)
print(instance)
```

Суть в том, что `@jsonattr("myClass.json")` - это вызов функции, которая должна вернуть декоратор (подобная ситуация как при создании [декоратора с параметрами для функции](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1143997)). Поэтому нужно три слоя функций:

- `jsonattr` - фабрика декораторов, которая при вызове примет параметры самого декоратора и вернет декоратор
- `decorator` - декоратор, который вернет функция `jsonattr`, вызовется при определении класса, при вызове вернет функцию-обертку или просто измененный класс
- `wrapper` - обертка для класса, вызовется при создании экземпляра класса, должна вернуть созданный объект класса. По сути эта обертка нужна только если нужно добавить какое-то поведение при создании экземпляра класса, в других случаях в декораторе можно просто менять класс, и его возвращать из декоратора, без использования обертки.

---

Дальше, если нужно сделать ключи и значения атрибутами класса (буквально по заданию, атрибуты будут прописаны для самого класса):

```
import json


def jsonattr(filepath):
    def decorator(cls):
        with open(filepath) as f:
            file = json.load(f)
        
        for key, value in file.items():
            setattr(cls, key, value)

        # Тут wrapper не нужен, т.к. изменили сам класс, его же и возвращаем
        return cls
    
    return decorator


@jsonattr("myClass.json")
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        pass
    
    def __str__(self):
        return '{}({})'.format(self.__class__.__name__, ', '.join('{}={!r}'.format(key, getattr(self, key))
            for key in filter(lambda key: not key.startswith('_'), dir(self))))


instance = MyClass()
print(instance)
```

Также можно сделать ключи и значения атрибутами объекта (значения будут недоступны из класса, и независимы в каждом объекте):

```
import json
from copy import deepcopy


def jsonattr(filepath):
    def decorator(cls):
        with open(filepath) as f:
            file = json.load(f)
            
        def wrapper(*args):
            obj = cls(*args)
            
            for key, value in file.items():
                # Делаем глубокую копию каждого значения, чтобы значения были независимы в каждом объекте
                setattr(obj, key, deepcopy(value))
            
            return obj

        return wrapper
    
    return decorator


@jsonattr("myClass.json")
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        pass
    
    def __str__(self):
        return '{}({})'.format(self.__class__.__name__, ', '.join('{}={!r}'.format(key, getattr(self, key))
            for key in filter(lambda key: not key.startswith('_'), dir(self))))


instance = MyClass()
print(instance)
```

Под независимостью я имею в виду, что если из файла загружен такой json: `{'foo': []}` - то при добавлении значений в список значения будут отображаться только в одном из объектов - в том где мы эти значения добавляем. Если делать атрибуты для класса целиком, то при добавлении значений в такой список они будут видны во всех экземплярах (если значение атрибута полностью перезаписано в каком-то экземпляре - то в нем новые значения отображаться не будет).