# Ошибка "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable" при использовании декоратора с параметрами

Tags: python, декоратор

Новичок в декораторах.

main.py:

```
def decoration(name):
    def wrapper(func):
        func(name)
    return wrapper

my_list = []
```

hello.py:

```
from main import decoration, my_list
@decoration(name="Артур")
def func(name):
    my_list.append(name)
func()
```

При запуске hello.py выходит ошибка:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Что делать?

Comment: Для декораторов с параметрами нужно делать "фабрику" декораторов. См. тут пример `decorator_maker_with_arguments`: https://habr.com/ru/post/141501/

Answer (score 1):

Есть две большие разницы:

- `@decoration` - просто декоратор
- `@decoration(name="Артур")` (или `@decoration()`) - вызов функции, которая должна вернуть декоратор

В вашем случае `decoration` вызывается с параметром `name="Артур"`, потом то, что она вернула (функцию `wrapper`), интерпретатор пытается использовать как декоратор - т.е. передать туда декорируемую функцию (`func`), и этот декоратор должен вернуть функцию-обертку (которая должна заменить декорируемую функцию), но он сразу вызывает функцию `func`, и ничего не возвращает, что для Python означает, что возвращено `None`. Получается, что в результате декорирования функция `func` была заменена на `None`, в итоге при попытке вызова этой функции вылетает ошибка `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`.

Чтобы работало правильно, нужно сделать чтобы функция `decoration` возвращала декоратор (который уже в свою очередь будет возвращать функцию `wrapper`):

```
def decoration(name):
    def decorator(func):
        # wrapper без параметров, т.к. в конце func() вызывается без параметров
        def wrapper():  
            func(name)
        
        return wrapper
    
    return decorator


my_list = []


@decoration(name="Артур")
def func(name):
    my_list.append(name)


func()


print(my_list)  # выведет ['Артур']
```

К прочтению:

- [Понимаем декораторы в Python'e, шаг за шагом. Шаг 1](https://habr.com/ru/post/141411/)
- [Понимаем декораторы в Python'e, шаг за шагом. Шаг 2](https://habr.com/ru/post/141501/) (случай декоратора с параметрами рассматривается в разделе "Вызов декоратора с различными аргументами")